# How do we make keyboard appear below textView in swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift2

I have done keyboard appearing below textfield using

on View did Load adding a observer()

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Gold_Loan_First_ViewController.keyboardDidShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Gold_Loan_First_ViewController.keyboardWillBeHidden(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

And then updating the frame

```
weak var activeField: UITextField?

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeField = nil


}
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField==txtOTP {
        txtOTP.errorMessage=""
    }
  return true
}
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeField = textField

}




func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification)
{
    if let activeField = self.activeField,
        let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0.0)
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        var aRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.size.height
        if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin)) {
            self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
        }
    }


}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification)
{
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}
```

But how do I do it for a textView. I tried the same code with didBeginEditing  of textView with no positive effect

Comment: What problem are you facing? try to check you are able to get the height of keyboard?
if not you can use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey `

Comment: If i did the same code for textview the keyboard overlays the textview.

Comment: I do get the height though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the easy and no code of line solution is to use the following pods in your app.

[IQKeyboardManger](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

Later you need to just import that in App Delegate and add this two lines of code in didfinishLaunching method:

```
  IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
```

Your problem will be solved for whole app.

For Swift 5:

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
```

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through such a situation. For this first I added extension in my `UiViewController` :

```
    extension CCViewController : UITextViewDelegate {
        func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            // write code as per your requirements
        }

        func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
             // write code as per your requirements
        }

        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.p_adjustMessageFieldFrameForTextView(textView)
        }
    }

    // Defining the p_adjustMessageFieldFrameForTextView method

    fileprivate func p_adjustMessageFieldFrameForTextView(_ textView : UITextView) {
            var finalheight : CGFloat = textView.contentSize.height + 10
            var kMaxMessageFieldHeight : CGFloat = 50
            if  (finalheight > kMaxMessageFieldHeight) {
                finalheight = kMaxMessageFieldHeight;
            } else if (finalheight < kCommentTextViewHeight){
                finalheight = kCommentTextViewHeight;
            }

            scrollView!.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: kNavBarHeight + statuBarHeight, width: SCREEN_WIDTH,height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - finalheight - keyboardRect!.size.height - kNavBarHeight - statuBarHeight)
// It is there for understanding that we have to calculate the exact frame of scroll view

            commentTextView!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: bottomOfView(scrollView!.view), width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: finalheight)
            self.p_setContentOffsetWhenKeyboardIsVisible()
        }

    // Defining the p_setContentOffsetWhenKeyboardIsVisible method

    fileprivate func p_setContentOffsetWhenKeyboardIsVisible() {
            // here you can set the offset of your scroll view
        }
```

Also there is a method named `bottomView()` :

```
func bottomOfView(_ view : UIView) -> CGFloat {
        return view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [TPKAScrollViewController.h](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding/master/TPKeyboardAvoiding/TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.h) & [TPKAScrollViewController.m](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding/master/TPKeyboardAvoiding/TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.m) files by using Bridging Header.

While dragging these objective-C file to your swift project, it will automatically ask for Create Bridging. Create Bridging Header and Import `#import "TPKAScrollViewController.h"` to YourApp-Bridging-Header.h file.

[image]

After that, simply select your scrollView in XIB and change its class to `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView` as showing below.

[image]

Comment: hi @Jeesson_7 try this one, it works 100% on textfield as well as textView.

Answer (score 1):

Salman Ghumsani is Right.

Please change `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` to `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`.

[Apple Debeloper Document: Keyboard Notification User Info Keys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/keyboard_notification_user_info_keys)

**UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey**

The key for an NSValue object containing a CGRect that identifies the `ending` frame rectangle of the keyboard in screen coordinates. The frame rectangle reflects the current orientation of the device.

**UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey**

The key for an 
NSValue
 object containing a 
CGRect
 that identifies the `starting` frame rectangle of the keyboard in screen coordinates. The frame rectangle reflects the current orientation of the device.

**Conclusion**

So, if u use `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` u might get the keyboard height to `0`. Causing the system thought `UITextView` was not covered.

Comment: I tried it . It doesn't work. Moreover I am getting the height when its textfield with the same code

Comment: 1. `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` works for `textfield` but not `textview`

Comment: 2. I tried, it worked. Did you forget to change `activeField` to `activeTextView` ?

Comment: maybe you can try my sample: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BoOI8OgHTtyPhoj2cnn8rpoFCF0qt1jh

Answer (score 1):

Find the correct height of keyboard and assign it to the bottom constraint of the textView or reduce the y position of textView.
Like:

**Step-1:** 
make a property keyboardHeight in you viewController.

`var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0.0`

**Step-2:** Make `@IBOutlet` of bottom constraint of the textView.

`@IBOutlet weak var textViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!`

**Step-3:**

```
fileprivate func addKeyboardNotification() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

fileprivate func removeKeyboardNotification() {
    IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnabled = true
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

Copy & paste these functions to your view controllers, and call `self.addKeyboardNotification()` in `viewDidLoad()` and  of you viewController

**Step-4:**

```
deinit {
    self.removeKeyboardNotification()
}
```

also add this code to your viewController.

**Step-5:**

```
    func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue, self.keyboardHeight <= 0.0 {
        self.keyboardHeight = keboardFrame.height + 45.0 //(Add 45 if your keyboard have toolBar if not then remove it)
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.textViewBottomConstraint.constant = self.keyboardHeight
    }, completion: { (success) in
    })
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.textViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0.0
    }, completion: { (success) in
    })
}
```

That's it to manage the textView with keyboard.
If you don't want to use `textViewBottomConstraint` the you can work with the y position of the textView.